# How do you use Git within Eclipse as it was intended?

Tags: eclipse, git

I've recently been looking at using Git to eventually replace the CVS repository we have at work.  However after watching [Linus Torvalds' video on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XpnKHJAok8) about Git it seems that every tutorial I find suggests using Git in the same way CVS is used except that you have a local repository which I agree is very useful for speed and distribution.

However the tutorials suggest that what you do is each clone the repository you want to develop on from a remote location and that when changes are made you commit locally building up a history to help with merge control.  When you are ready to commit your changes you then push them to the remote location, but first you fetch changes to check for merge conflicts (just like CVS).

However in Linus' video he describe the functionality of Git as a group of developers working on some code pushing and fetching from each other as needed, not using a remote location i.e. a centralized location.  He also describes people pushing their changes out to verifiers who fetch and push code also.  So you can see it's possible to create scalable structure within a company also.

My question is can anybody point me in the direction of some tutorials that actually explain how to do this distributed development of code using Git so that developers push and fetch code from each other with out committing to the remote repository and if possible it would be very nice to have this tutorials Eclipsed based.

Thanks in advance,
Alexei Blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at alblue's blog entry on [Gerrit](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/06/running-gerrit-with-jenkinshudson.html)

This shows a workflow different from the classic centralized server such as CVS or SVN. Superficially it looks similar as you pull the source from a central Git server, but you push your commits to the Gerrit server that can compile and test the code to make sure it works before eventually pushing the changes to the central Git server.

Now instead of pushing the changes to Gerrit, you could have pushed the code to your pair programming buddy and he could have manually reviewed and tested the code.

Or maybe you're going on holiday and a colleague will finish the task you've started. No problem, just push your changes to their Git repo.

Git doesn't treat any of these other Git instances any different from each other. From Git's perspective, none of them are special.

Comment: I'd tick both answers if I could because they've given me excellent information, cheers guys.  We current use hudson for our builds of the CVS repositories so using Gerrit would be a smooth transition, cheers Steve :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know any specific tutorial about this. In general, for connecting to a repository, you have to be running a git server that listens (and authenticates) to git requests.

To have a specific repository for each developer is possible - but each repository needs that server component. It is possible to store multiple repositories on the same computer, that allows reducing the number of servers required.

However, for other reasons it is beneficial to have some kind of central structure (e.g. a repository for stuff to be released; or a repository for stuff not verified yet). This structure is not required to be a single central repository, but multiple ones with well-defined workflows regarding the data move between repositories (e.g. if code from the verification repository is validated, it should be pushed to the release repository).

In other words, you should be ready to create Git servers (e.g. see http://tumblr.intranation.com/post/766290565/how-set-up-your-own-private-git-server-linux for details; but there are other tutorials for this as well), and define workflows for your own company to use it.

Additionally, I recommend looking at AlBlue's blog series called [Git Tip of the Week](http://alblue.bandlem.com/search/label/gtotw).

Finally, to ease the introduction I suggest to first introduce Git as a direct replacement for CVS, and then present the other changes one by one.

Comment: Given the OP's name, I think he's already come across alblue, otherwise it's one big coincidence...

Comment: Lol, I've seen his blog post's while looking around for tips and tutorials on Git but there's no relationship, just coincidence ^.^